# How i make a multiple diagonal sections with css and Responsive

Tags: html, css, diagonal, skew

I've been trying to make a diagonal sections using css but if I use the border property brings me problems in the responsive and the text 
so that it is also diagonal do you recommend for this section.

Thank you very much

[image]